# Apache Camel - JpaConsumer failed polling endpoint

Tags: java, jpa, apache-camel, apache-karaf

I'm getting the following error trying to poll a JPA entity Person. There's no error in the code. Everything compiles ok with a mvn clean install and the Person entity does exist in the net.lr.tutorial.karaf.camel.jpa2jms.model package. I have installed all the necessary features I believe and I know it's correctly connection to the database because it's creating a sequence database for the primary key.

```
2014-01-30 21:33:59,848 | WARN  | jms.model.Person | JpaConsumer                      |  
125 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.12.0 | Consumer   
Consumer[jpa://net.lr.tutorial.karaf.camel.jpa2jms.model.Person?consumer.delay=3500] 
failed polling endpoint: 
Endpoint[jpa://net.lr.tutorial.karaf.camel.jpa2jms.model.Person?consumer.delay=3500]. 
Will try again at next poll. Caused by: 
[org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException - An error occurred while parsing the 
query filter "select x from Person x". Error message: The name "Person" is not a 
recognized entity or identifier. Perhaps you meant Person, which is a close match. Known 
entity names: [Person]] 
<openjpa-2.1.1-r422266:1148538 nonfatal user error> 
org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: An error occurred while parsing the 
query filter "select x from Person x". Error message: The name "Person" is not a 
recognized entity or identifier. Perhaps you meant Person, which is a close match. Known 
entity names: [Person]
```

Any ideas?

Sean

Comment: Did you reset the name attribute of the `Person` entity, i.e. `@Entity(name="Person")`?

Comment: Yes I did. My JPA class looks like - @Entity(name = "person")
[code]@XmlType
@XmlRootElement
public class Person {[/code]

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

- Remove the `name` attribute of the `@Entity` annotation if possible.
- Check if the correct `Person` class is added to `persistence.xml`. It should be `net.lr.tutorial.karaf.camel.jpa2jms.model.Person` and not `jms.model.Person`

I hope, it helps.